# javascript validation failed if i submit a form appended using ajax resposnse in a present html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Apologies for my English. My Java Script validation is failed which prevent a form from uploading if fields is empty, actually it works find if from is already present inside the HTML (that is for add part) .

If i append the same form calling same Java Script validation function having same fields inside of it only the difference is I append this form using AJAX response from some PHP page (`add_selection_ajax.php`) because i need to load values from database this time on that form and i need to append it using AJAX that is limitation of the my project i have to fellow to work in that way.

This is function call AJAX:

```
function editSelectionOptn(sel_optn_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'add_selection_ajax.php',
          data: { sel_optn_id:sel_optn_id},
          success:function(data){
            // alert(data);
             $("#edit").append(data);
             document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'block';
             document.getElementById('exposeMask').style.display = 'block';

           }
        });
    }
```

Java Script validation:

```
function validateInputOptn()
{

    alert(document.sel_optn.image_thumb.value);
    alert(document.sel_optn.image_thumb.value);
    if (document.sel_optn.image_thumb.value==null || document.sel_optn.image_thumb.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please select thumbnail image.");
        document.sel_optn.image_thumb.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.sel_optn.image.value==null || document.sel_optn.image.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please select image.");
        document.sel_optn.image.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.sel_optn.selection_optn_title.value==null || document.sel_optn.selection_optn_title.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter subcatagory title.");
        document.sel_optn.selection_optn_title.focus();
        return false;
    }


}
```

add_selection_ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['sel_optn_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['sel_optn_id']))
    {
        $table=" tbl_selection_options";
                $optn_sel_id=$_POST['sel_optn_id'];
                $db->selectQuery($table,"where id='".$_POST['sel_optn_id']."'","id, option_title, option_img, selection_id");
                $value=mysql_fetch_assoc($db->result);
?>
                <h3>Edit Selection</h3>

                <!-- input form. you can press enter too -->
                <form action="" name="sel_optn" id="sel_optn" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateInputOptn();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?=$_POST['sel_optn_id']?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="selection_id" id="selection_id" value="<?=$value['selection_id']?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="page_start" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['start'])) echo $_GET['start']; ?>" />
                    <p>Thumbnail (100 x 100) <input type="file" name="image_thumb" id="image_thumb" value="" ></button></p>
                    <p>Large Image (750 x 515) <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value=""> Browse </button></p>
                    <p>Title: <input type="text" name="selection_optn_title" id="selection_optn_title" value="<?php if(isset($value['option_title'])) echo $value['option_title']; ?>" class="overlay-input" />
                    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="cancle()"> Cancel </button>
                    <button type="submit"> Save </button></p>
                </form>
<?php
    }
```

Here is the HTML page which contains both form add and edit part. Add part validation works properly. It is also calling the same Java Script function as edit was calling.

edit_selection.php

```
<div class="modal" id="add">
  <h3>Add Selection</h3>


  <form action="" name="sel_optn" id="sel_optn" method="post" onsubmit="return validateInputOptn();"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="selection_id" id="selection_id" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
    <p>Thumbnail (100 x 100) <input type="file" name="image_thumb" id="image_thumb" value="" ></button></p>
    <p>Large Image (750 x 515) <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value=""> </button></p>
    <p>Title:  <input type="text" name="selection_optn_title" id="selection_optn_title" value="" class="overlay-input" />
    <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
    <button type="submit"> Save </button></p>

  </form>


</div>


<div class="modal" id="edit">



</div>
```

Both add and edit part remain hidden on page load only appear once clicked on add or edit button on the page

Even i use `.live()` function of jquery since it is deprecated for new version of jquery so i had to use `.on()` function but `.on()` function is not working too.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax to create new elements, jQuery doesn't know them since he is applying on $( document ).ready (at the page load).

If you want your jQuery validation scripts to work, you need to scope something bigger, higher in the DOM which hasn't been changed and then go down the DOM to find your newly created elements and apply your validation patterns on them.